# Is there a shortcut to calculate integrals for different types of probability density functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integral, probability-density

In a case like this,

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

exponential_distribution = lambda x, lam: lam*np.exp(-lam*x)
result = quad(exponential_distribution, 0.25, 0.75, args=0.1)[0]
```

I'm imagining something like that

```
from magic_library import integrate_distribution

result = integrate_distribution(distribution='exponential', parameter=[0.1], a=0.25, b=0.75)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the already defined distributions in `scipy.stats` for most of you purposes.  For the case of an exponential distribution, you can create an instance of the distribution with frozen parameters (i.e. `lam`).  That object has methods you can call to manage the integration such as `cdf`, the cumulative distribution function for the exponential distribution.

Integration from `x0 to x1` is then just the difference between the values of the `cdf` at those two points.  For the `expon` class, the `scale` parameter is equivalent to `1/lam` in your example function.

```py
from scipy import stats

lam = 0.1
exponential_distribution = stats.expon(scale=1/lam)

exponential_distribution.cdf(0.75) - exponential_distribution.cdf(0.25)
# returns:
0.04756642569977977
```

We can compare this to the method you used for integration and see it gives the same answer.

```py
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

exponential_distribution = lambda x, lam: lam*np.exp(-lam*x)
quad(exponential_distribution, 0.25, 0.75, args=0.1)[0]
# returns:
0.04756642569977978
```

Comment: My main concern was not to have to type in the formulas myself. Problem solved, thank you very much.